# external/clearsilver/util/neo_err.h:88:69: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token

Tags: android, make, ubuntu-for-android, ubuntu-make

There is one error showed on my ubuntu 16.04 LTS system when `make` android 2.3.7 version , I do not know how to fix these problems ?

PS: this error has been shown after i install the `libswitch-perl` by typing the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install libswitch-perl
```

Error Message:

```
paultsai@paultsai-VirtualBox:~/android/aosp-2.3.x$ make -j8
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=2.3.7
TARGET_PRODUCT=full
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_SIMULATOR=false
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a
HOST_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=GINGERBREAD
============================================
find: ‘frameworks/base/frameworks/base/docs/html’: No such file or directory
find: ‘out/target/common/docs/gen’: No such file or directory
find: ‘frameworks/base/frameworks/base/docs/html’: No such file or directory
find: ‘out/target/common/docs/gen’: No such file or directory
find: ‘frameworks/base/frameworks/base/docs/html’: No such file or directory
find: ‘out/target/common/docs/gen’: No such file or directory
find: ‘frameworks/base/frameworks/base/docs/html’: No such file or directory
find: ‘out/target/common/docs/gen’: No such file or directory
find: ‘frameworks/base/frameworks/base/docs/html’: No such file or directory
find: ‘out/target/common/docs/gen’: No such file or directory
host C: libclearsilver-jni <= external/clearsilver/java-jni/j_neo_util.c
host C: libclearsilver-jni <= external/clearsilver/java-jni/j_neo_cs.c
host StaticLib: libhost (out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libhost_intermediates/libhost.a)
echo out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libhost_intermediates/pseudolocalize.o out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libhost_intermediates/CopyFile.o | xargs ar crsP  out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libhost_intermediates/libhost.a
host C: libneo_util <= external/clearsilver/util/neo_rand.c
host C: libneo_util <= external/clearsilver/util/neo_files.c
host C: libneo_util <= external/clearsilver/util/ulist.c
host C: libneo_util <= external/clearsilver/util/neo_hdf.c
host C: libneo_util <= external/clearsilver/util/neo_str.c
host C: libneo_util <= external/clearsilver/util/neo_date.c
In file included from external/clearsilver/util/ulist.c:19:0:
external/clearsilver/util/ulist.c: In function ‘uListInit’:
external/clearsilver/util/neo_err.h:88:69: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
    nerr_raisef(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__,e,f,__VA_ARGS__)
                                                                     ^
external/clearsilver/util/ulist.c:64:12: note: in expansion of macro ‘nerr_raise’
     return nerr_raise(NERR_NOMEM, "Unable to create ULIST: Out of memory");
            ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_err.h:88:69: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
    nerr_raisef(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__,e,f,__VA_ARGS__)
                                                                     ^
external/clearsilver/util/ulist.c:70:12: note: in expansion of macro ‘nerr_raise’
     return nerr_raise(NERR_NOMEM, "Unable to create ULIST: Out of memory");
            ^
external/clearsilver/util/ulist.c: In function ‘uListPop’:
external/clearsilver/util/neo_err.h:88:69: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
    nerr_raisef(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__,e,f,__VA_ARGS__)
                                                                     ^
external/clearsilver/util/ulist.c:124:12: note: in expansion of macro ‘nerr_raise’
     return nerr_raise(NERR_OUTOFRANGE, "uListPop: empty list");
            ^
In file included from external/clearsilver/java-jni/j_neo_util.c:6:0:
external/clearsilver/java-jni/j_neo_util.c: In function ‘jni_fileload_cb’:
external/clearsilver/java-jni/../util/neo_err.h:88:69: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
    nerr_raisef(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__,e,f,__VA_ARGS__)
                                                                     ^
external/clearsilver/java-jni/j_neo_util.c:257:12: note: in expansion of macro ‘nerr_raise’
     return nerr_raise(NERR_ASSERT,
            ^
external/clearsilver/java-jni/../util/neo_err.h:88:69: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
    nerr_raisef(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__,e,f,__VA_ARGS__)
                                                                     ^
external/clearsilver/java-jni/j_neo_util.c:268:12: note: in expansion of macro ‘nerr_raise’
     return nerr_raise(NERR_ASSERT,
            ^
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libneo_util_intermediates/ulist.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from external/clearsilver/util/neo_files.c:26:0:
external/clearsilver/util/neo_files.c: In function ‘ne_listdir_fmatch’:
In file included from external/clearsilver/util/neo_hdf.c:24:0:
external/clearsilver/util/neo_hdf.c: In function ‘_alloc_hdf’:
external/clearsilver/util/neo_err.h:88:69: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
    nerr_raisef(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__,e,f,__VA_ARGS__)
                                                                     ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_hdf.c:62:12: note: in expansion of macro ‘nerr_raise’
     return nerr_raise (NERR_NOMEM, "Unable to allocate memory for hdf element");
            ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_err.h:88:69: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
    nerr_raisef(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__,e,f,__VA_ARGS__)
                                                                     ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_files.c:219:12: note: in expansion of macro ‘nerr_raise’
     return nerr_raise(NERR_ASSERT, "Invalid call to ne_listdir_fmatch");
            ^
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libclearsilver-jni_intermediates/j_neo_util.o] Error 1
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libneo_util_intermediates/neo_files.o] Error 1
external/clearsilver/util/neo_hdf.c: In function ‘hdf_set_attr’:
external/clearsilver/util/neo_err.h:88:69: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
    nerr_raisef(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__,e,f,__VA_ARGS__)
                                                                     ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_hdf.c:409:12: note: in expansion of macro ‘nerr_raise’
     return nerr_raise(NERR_ASSERT, "Unable to set attribute on none existant node");
            ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_hdf.c: In function ‘_set_value’:
In file included from external/clearsilver/util/neo_str.c:22:0:
external/clearsilver/util/neo_str.c: In function ‘string_appendvf’:
external/clearsilver/util/neo_err.h:88:69: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
    nerr_raisef(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__,e,f,__VA_ARGS__)
                                                                     ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_str.c:167:14: note: in expansion of macro ‘nerr_raise’
       return nerr_raise(NERR_NOMEM, 
              ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_str.c: In function ‘string_array_split’:
external/clearsilver/util/neo_err.h:88:69: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
    nerr_raisef(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__,e,f,__VA_ARGS__)
                                                                     ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_str.c:223:12: note: in expansion of macro ‘nerr_raise’
     return nerr_raise (NERR_ASSERT, "separator must be at least one character");
            ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_err.h:88:69: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
    nerr_raisef(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__,e,f,__VA_ARGS__)
                                                                     ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_hdf.c:648:14: note: in expansion of macro ‘nerr_raise’
       return nerr_raise(NERR_NOMEM, "Unable to allocate memory");
              ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_err.h:88:69: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
    nerr_raisef(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__,e,f,__VA_ARGS__)
                                                                     ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_hdf.c:795:16: note: in expansion of macro ‘nerr_raise’
         return nerr_raise(NERR_NOMEM, "Unable to allocate memory");
                ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_hdf.c: In function ‘hdf_set_valuevf’:
external/clearsilver/util/neo_err.h:88:69: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
    nerr_raisef(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__,e,f,__VA_ARGS__)
                                                                     ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_hdf.c:869:12: note: in expansion of macro ‘nerr_raise’
     return nerr_raise(NERR_NOMEM, "Unable to allocate memory for format string");
            ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_hdf.c: In function ‘_copy_attr’:
external/clearsilver/util/neo_err.h:88:69: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
    nerr_raisef(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__,e,f,__VA_ARGS__)
                                                                     ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_hdf.c:1028:14: note: in expansion of macro ‘nerr_raise’
       return nerr_raise(NERR_NOMEM, "Unable to allocate copy of HDF_ATTR");
              ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_err.h:88:69: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
    nerr_raisef(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__,e,f,__VA_ARGS__)
                                                                     ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_hdf.c:1036:14: note: in expansion of macro ‘nerr_raise’
       return nerr_raise(NERR_NOMEM, "Unable to allocate copy of HDF_ATTR");
              ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_hdf.c: In function ‘hdf_write_string’:
external/clearsilver/util/neo_err.h:88:69: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
    nerr_raisef(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__,e,f,__VA_ARGS__)
                                                                     ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_hdf.c:1342:28: note: in expansion of macro ‘nerr_raise’
     if (*s == NULL) return nerr_raise(NERR_NOMEM, "Unable to allocate empty string");
                            ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_hdf.c: In function ‘hdf_read_file’:
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libneo_util_intermediates/neo_str.o] Error 1
external/clearsilver/util/neo_err.h:88:69: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
    nerr_raisef(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__,e,f,__VA_ARGS__)
                                                                     ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_hdf.c:1834:12: note: in expansion of macro ‘nerr_raise’
     return nerr_raise(NERR_ASSERT, "Can't read NULL file");
            ^
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libneo_util_intermediates/neo_hdf.o] Error 1
```

Comment: I have nearly the exact same error, OS, Android target... Did you solve this? I'm an AOSP noob.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!